# Open vacuum response with Nokogiri in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I implemented the vacuum gem and tried to look up some books:

```
req = Vacuum.new
  .configure(
    aws_access_key_id:     '...',
    aws_secret_access_key: '...',
    associate_tag:         'biz-val'
  )

  params = { 'Operation'   => 'ItemSearch',
             'SearchIndex' => 'Books',
             'Keywords'    => 'Books' }

  res = req.get(query: params)
```

I tried to parse the result with Nokogiri:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(res))
```

and then got:

```
no implicit conversion of Excon::Response into String
```

The plain output of the result is:

```
#<Excon::Response:0x007fcffd0b0778>
```

which does not look very XMLish, rather like an array.  I've never seen that kind of result and am a little bit lost on what to do here, so, probably, opening it with Nokogiri is not the right way.

How should I parse a vacuum result to output the API call?

Comment: You're trying to `open` the response, which won't work. `open` in the usual Nokogiri context comes from OpenURI, which overrides the Kernel or IO `open` command to read from a socket. `open` expects a string which is the URL to open. `res` is not a string, hence the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The XML is saved in the Excon object. Simply calling `body` on it and tadaaa: XML.